# Unable to Communicate between components on different pages using Lightning message channel

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm using Lightning Message Channel to communicate between components on 2 different Pages and it's not working. The communication works when I put both these components on the same page.

Can someone please tell what's missing and why the communication is not working

**Component that publishes to message channel**

HTML

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Publish - LWC">
        <button type="button" onclick={publishMC}>Send Message</button>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

js

```
import { LightningElement , api ,wire} from 'lwc';
import { MessageContext , createMessageContext, releaseMessageContext,publish } from 'lightning/messageService';
import SAMPLEMC from '@salesforce/messageChannel/TestMessageChannel__c'
export default class LMCPublish extends LightningElement {
    acctInfo = {};
    @wire(MessageContext)
    context;
    publishMC(){
        acctInfo.Name = 'Test Name';
        acctInfo.Phone = '9999999999';   
        const message = {
            recordData: this.objAcctInfo
        };
        publish(this.context,SAMPLEMC,message);
    }
}
```

**Components the subscribes:**

HTML

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Subscribe LMC">
        <button type="button" onclick={getMessage}>Get Message</button>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

JS

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { createMessageContext, releaseMessageContext, subscribe, unsubscribe ,APPLICATION_SCOPE} from 'lightning/messageService';
import SAMPLEMC from "@salesforce/messageChannel/TestMessageChannel__c";
export default class LMCSubscribe extends LightningElement {
    objReceivedMessage = {};
    @wire(MessageContext) messageContext ;
    channel;
    subscription = null;
    receivedMessage;
    getMessage(){
        if (this.subscription) {
            return;
        }
        this.subscription = subscribe(
            this.messageContext,
            SAMPLEMC, (message) => {
                this.handleMessage(message);
            },
            {scope: APPLICATION_SCOPE});
    }      
    handleMessage(message) {
        console.log('message : ' ,message);
        this.receivedMessage = message ? JSON.stringify(message, null, '\t') : 'no message payload';
        console.log('this.receivedMessage : ',this.receivedMessage);
    }
}
```

When placed on the same page, communication works perfectly. handleMessessage() method in subscriber is called and received message is displayed in console. However, when placed on different pages - handleMessage() method doesn't get called at all. What do you think is missing here?

Answer (score 3):

LMS is for communication across DOM which means that it is for the component which is on the same tab but can be a VF in an iframe, or aura component. This is evident from the section **[When should I use LMS](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/10/lightning-message-service-developer-preview.html)**?

If you want to communicate between pages on different tabs, you will need to rely on [`session storage` and events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28230845/communication-between-tabs-or-windows).

> If you’ve tried putting a Visualforce page in Lightning Experience and
>   you dreaded figuring out how to work with raw iframes and postMessage
>   to speak to Lightning Components, this service is for you. Our hope is
>   that developers will see value in this handy service and integrate
>   their existing Visualforce-based UIs into Lightning Experience with
>   first-class communication.
>
> Ask yourself, is there any time you want your Visualforce page to
>   communicate with components on its containing Lightning Page? Those
>   components can be Lightning Web Components, Aura Components or other
>   Visualforce pages on the same Lightning Page. If so, you can’t go
>   wrong with LMS.

Comment: Hi @manjit5190, How to use localStorage & pass it in subscribe (message)=>{this.handleMessage(message)} https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/343833/how-to-pass-the-data-from-one-lwc-to-another-lwc-during-navigation-when-using-li/343845?noredirect=1#comment505648_343845
from above link, I can publish the data but can not subscribe it when Navigating to another LWC.